# Using Modem in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, modem

How can I use this modem in Linux Mint ?

[image]

Comment: *"only power source required"* and *"4/3G + WiFi"* suggests it's just an wifi access point for 3G/4G internets

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What didn't work, and what error messages did you get?

Answer (score 2):

It's a 3-in-1 device that can work as:

- A 4G USB dongle connected to a PC or laptop
- A 4G USB WiFi cellular router/hotspot,
- USB flash drive when adding a MicroSD card.

For the first feature, you will need to connect it to the USB port of your PC or laptop, and depending on the drivers that it needs it could work or not.

For the second one, there's nothing complicated to configure. It will work as a Wifi hotspot, connect your Linux Mint to the Wifi network it provides and it will act as a router to send traffic via 4G to Internet.

Comment: It should work anyway and no user installable drivers required. This devices typically use a "USB to Ethernet" so it'll be recognized as any other Ethernet. Config is then done in any web browser with the gateway IP.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment, the box says "Only power source required", so there's no cable making a network connection to your computer.  The only cable supplies power.

The box also says "Internet sharing up to 10 wifi devices".  This device plugs into power, you configure it to use your LTE mobile data service, and configure it to offer a local wifi network.  Then you configure your Linux computer to connect to this device's wifi network.